# How to change active WorkingSets programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, working-set

I started implementing a custom configuration dialog for a custom working set. Now I wanted to implement an activation/deactivation mechanism (checkboxes) for the visible `WorkingSets` in the `Project Explorer` like the one you get via `Select Working Set...`, so the user does not have to switch between two GUIs.

The GUI is already working, but my two problems are:

1. Getting the currently active working sets (e.g. in the Project Explorer/Navigator)
2. Setting active working sets

I tried to work with `IWorkingSet.isVisible()`, but the function returns `true` for all working sets. How can I get the currently active working sets for those views and how can I change them programmatically?

Comment: The old, deprecated, resource navigator had an `IResourceNavigator` interface with a `setWorkingSet`. I don't see anything similar for Project Explorer so it may not provide a way to do this.

Comment: I was wondering if the `isVisible()` operation of `IWorkingSet` might help in some way, but I haven't found a way to change the return value.